# Pattern for Typescript generic parameters that can sometimes be undefined?

Tags: typescript, generics, inheritance

I want a class hierarchy where some implementations of a base class allow a member to be undefined, while in others this will never be the case. I've been trying to work out how to even ask this all day because I've tried a few approaches and run into different language limitations depending on what I do.  I'll try to summarize the problem with an example of an approach I've tried:

```
function f(foo: Foo): number { return foo.bar; }

class Foo { bar: number; }

abstract class Base<T extends Foo | undefined> {
    data: T;
    public f(): number {
        if (!this.data) { return -1; }
        return f(this.data); // bad: this.data is still `Foo | undefined` not just `Foo`
    }
}

class Always extends Base<Foo> {
  constructor() { super(); this.data = new Foo(); }
}

class Sometimes extends Base<Foo | undefined> {}

let a = new Always();
let s = new Sometimes();
a.data.bar = 1; // good: no error because `a.data` must not be undefined
s.data.bar = 1; // good: compiler flags this because s.data can be undefined
```

The line above that I labeled "bad" is the issue -- because you still [can't narrow a union generic](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995) there is no way to use a simple guard to assert that `data` is not undefined.  I can of course write `f(this.data as Foo)` but I want to avoid doing that everywhere I reference it if possible.

I've briefly played with conditional types by adding a second generic parameter that `extends boolean` but I haven't been able to make that work either.  Basically, all the solutions I've worked out on my own break one of the 3 lines with comments in the example -- `f(this.data)`, `a.data.bar` always being valid, or `s.data.bar` always being invalid if you haven't already checked that `s.data` is defined.

Comment: I don't think you will get an answer better than `f(this.data!);`

Comment: Thanks Titian, I was afraid that might be the case.  I was kind of hoping that maybe I was overlooking something, like having `T extends Foo` then specifying a separate flag to have `data: T` vs `data: T | undefined` (something something conditional types?) but couldn't make it work.

Comment: I spoke too soon, I have a solution that uses  an extra type parameter. Conditional types are difficult to use as long as they still have unresolved type parameters you end up doing a lot of type assertions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are open to using a second type parameter to represent the possibility of undefined, this works:

```
function f(foo: Foo): number { return foo.bar; }

class Foo { bar: number; }


abstract class Base<T extends Foo, TUndefiend extends undefined> {
    data!: T | TUndefiend;
    public f(): number {
        if (!this.data) { return -1; }
        return f(this.data); // ok now
    }
}

class Always extends Base<Foo, never> {
  constructor() { super(); this.data = new Foo(); }
}

class Sometimes extends Base<Foo, undefined> {}

let a = new Always();
let s = new Sometimes();
a.data.bar = 1; // good: no error because `a.data` must not be undefined
s.data.bar = 1; // good: compiler flags this because s.data can be undefined
```

Type guards will not narrow into a type parameter, but if there are two different type parameters in a union that appears to work just fine.

The extra type parameter (`TUndefined`) will evaporate if we pass in `never` as `T | never` is `T` and everything works as expected in the derived `Always` class. If we pass in `undefined` then we have to check for undefined, again as expected in `Sometimes`

Comment: Perfect solution, exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!